# Only part of Google Map showing

Tags: php, javascript, css, google-maps

I am building small website, and i am having trouble displaying Google Map in the "location" section of the page.Take a look "http://sunlark.besaba.com/vile/12", click on a "Location" tab.
Tiny bit of map is shown in top left section, not all of it.
I took a look at the CSS, but i cant find what could be the problem...

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, this has to do with the map being created when hidden. You should be able to call a resize on the map once the tab is showing and that should correct the issue you are seeing.

For V3 API use this:

`google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`

In V2 API you can call `checkResize()` on your map object.

Comment: Me too! This would have taken me ages. Mariola - accept the answer.